# how to map sentences to user declared methods based on the meaning of that sentence?

Tags: c#, reflection, stanford-nlp

I have to map user defined sentences to particular methods.
for example, if there is sentence "Tune to 87.5 FM station" and i have a method "Tune(MediaDevices mediaDevice, double value)". I need to identify through the sentence that this method is to be called and parameters should be FM for mediaDevice and 87.5 for value.

I have tried using NLP dependency parser to identify the Action i.e "Tune" in this case and the values,i.e "FM" and "87.5". 
But how to map these action and value to this Method. Also there will be many methods related to tuner, so which method needs to be called is an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Type classType = Type.GetType("ClassName"); //In case method is in any other class.
ConstructorInfo classConstructor = classType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
object classObject = classConstructor.Invoke(new object[]{});
MethodInfo tune= magicType.GetMethod("Tune");
tune.Invoke(classObject , new object[]{arg1,arg2});
```

Include reflection.
Hope it helps.

Comment: i think this will help in cases where we know the method name i.e GetMethod("Tune"), we know that the method name is "Tune" . I have a case where i don't know the method name but i have to find through the action of sentence. what should i do in that case.

Comment: You already have mentioned you are using NLP parser to identify actions.